# DDEV IMPORT-DB: failed to extract provided archive: error during read of tar archive | err: archive/tar: invalid tar header

Tags: ddev

I am trying to import a mySQL database using DDEV but I am running into the following error:

```
ddev import-db --src=.ddev/imports/db/hfweb.tar.gz
Failed to import database db for hfweb: failed to extract provided archive: error during read of tar archive /home/devwalid/de-construct/bitbucket/hfweb/.ddev/imports/db/hfweb.tar.gz, err: archive/tar: invalid tar header
```

[Here is my current folder structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g5Rs.png)

---

Answer (score 0):

You tarball isn't gzipped, or isn't in proper tar format. Try inspecting it with `tar -tzf hfweb.tar.gz` and see if you can do that.

Although ddev can import from a gzipped tarball (containing an sql file) most people just use sql or gzipped sql. For example, if you have a file named `something.sql` you can gzip it with `gzip something.sql` and then use the resultant `something.sql.gz` with ddev, or just use the original `something.sql`.

Comment: thanks for that! I managed to import the db by running the following: 
gzip -dc /home/devwalid/de-construct/bitbucket/hfweb/.ddev/imports/db/hfweb.tar.gz | ddev import-db

However, when I am trying to visit my .ddev.site, I am hit with with another error:
"There was a database connection error or a problem with a query"

I assume then the db was not properly imported?

Comment: Now we've gone on to a different subject... you'd be better to join us in Discord where you can get more immediate responses as you're learning your way, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k - but you can use PhpMyAdmin (`ddev launch -p`) to take a look at the database you've imported and see what's in there.

Comment: Just FYI I'm seeing some buggy behavior from tar/gzip on Windows with latest git-bash. Are you on Windows with git 2.36?